# Exponential and log functions compose to identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, exponentiation

How to prove that the exponential function and the logarithm function are the inverses of each other? I want it the following way. We must use the definition as power series, and must verify that all the terms of the composition except the coefficent of $z$ vanish, and that the first degree term is $1$.

I can write down the proof for the coefficient of $x^n$ for arbitrary but fixed $n$ by explicit verification. But how to settle this for all $n$ at one go?

Comment: Do you care about real or complex numbers? You use x and z once each...

Comment: Kaestur: I want it to be true over any commutative ring, in fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a combinatorial proof.  If $A(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is an exponential generating function for the number of ways $a_n$ to put a certain structure on a set of size $n$, where $a_0 = 0$, then $\exp A(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ has coefficients $b_n$ which count the number of ways to split a set of size $n$ into subsets, each of which is given an $A$-structure.  For example, $A(x) = e^x - 1$ is the structure of "being a nonempty set," and $\exp A(x)$ counts the number of ways to partition a set into nonempty subsets.

Now $\log \frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ can be thought of as the structure of "being a cycle," which is to say there are $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange $n$ objects into a cycle $s_1 \to s_2 \to ... \to s_n \to s_1$.  So $\exp \log \frac{1}{1 - x}$ counts the number of ways to split $n$ objects up into disjoint cycles, which is the same as the number of permutations of $n$ by cycle decomposition.  So

$$\exp \log \frac{1}{1 - x} = \frac{1}{1 - x}.$$

A generalization of this argument lets you compute the [cycle index polynomials of the symmetric groups](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/).  Note that all of the above manipulations take place in the ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This takes place in the ring of divided-power series (integer sums of $x^n/n!$), not formal power series directly.

Comment: Would you happen to know an argument for the other direction of the composition, $\mathrm{log}\circ\mathrm{exp} = 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Qiaochu Yuan's proof is without doubt the most elegant. However, here is a purely formal argument using the derivative:

Let $L(x) = \log \frac 1{1-x} = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^n}n$. I will show that $\exp(L(x))=\frac 1{1-x}$.

Let $u(x)=\exp(L(x))$. By the chain rule for differentiation, we have
$$
u'(x) = L'(x)u(x).
$$
Noting that $L'(x)=(1-x)^{-1}$, the above can be rewritten as
$$
u(x)=(1-x)u'(x).
$$
Suppose $u(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_nx^n$, then comparing the coefficients of each power of $x$ in the preceding identity gives
$$
a_n = (n+1)a_{n+1} - na_n
$$ for each $n\geq 0$.
Also, $a_0=1$.
It follows that $a_n=1$ for all $n$, so $u(x)=\frac 1{1-x}$, as desired.

The reverse identity, $\log(\exp(x))=x$ is simpler; the chain rule tells us that the derivative of $\log(\exp(x))=1$.